# Add new class to parent if child has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

With my limited knowledge (or lack thereof) of JS, I'm trying to figure out a way to add a class to the parent of a specific element.

If been using this Fiddle to try to get it to work, but to no avail: https://jsfiddle.net/s0pca3cs/

```
if ($('.form__ select select').hasClass('error')) {
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
};
```

Anyone want to pinpoint here I mess it up? Thanks

Comment: [`$('.form__select select.error').parent().addClass('active');`](https://jsfiddle.net/s0pca3cs/2/)

Comment: Or the other way around, `$('.form__select').has('select.error').addClass('active');`

Comment: @Tushar—you should post full answers, with an explanation of how they fix the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `this` keyword in this context.

```
$('.form__select select.error').parent().addClass('active');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/s0pca3cs/2/)

Comment: Since there are multiple elements, this will only work for first matched element. Check comments for solution.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks, I missed that part. Updated.